# How To Get get data(Claim number and Status) from HTML using java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In my application, I have submitted a claim It generated the claim details along with claim number and Status. I need to extract the **Claim Number** and **Status** from the claim details.

HTML Code for the table containing Claim number and Status:

```
<div id="claim-num-success" style="width:50%; margin:0 auto; padding:25px; background:none; border:1px solid #d3d3d3; line-height:24px;"> <b>Service Name:</b> 7,500 MILES - NON-TURBO ENGINE
  <br> <b>Claim Number:</b> 02923240
  <br> <b>R/O Number:</b> 12000
  <br> <b>R/O Date:</b> 12/13/2017
  <br> <b>Claim Amount:</b> $40.00
  <br> <b>Status:</b> APPROVED
  <br> 
</div>
```

Comment: HTML Code for table containing Claim number and Status:
div id="claim-num-success" style="width:50%; margin:0 auto; padding:25px; background:none; border:1px solid #d3d3d3; line-height:24px;">
<b>Service Name:</b>
7,500 MILES - NON-TURBO ENGINE
<br>
<b>Claim Number:</b>
02923240
<br>
<b>R/O Number:</b>
12000
<br>
<b>R/O Date:</b>
12/13/2017
<br>
<b>Claim Amount:</b>
$40.00
<br>
<b>Status:</b>
APPROVED
<br>
</div>

Comment: I think it wont be possible if it's not inside any tag..and get that value

Comment: @Ankur Singh, there is some way to do the things :) I have posted the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can use below xpath to extract the value :

```
//div[@id='claim-num-success']/b[text()='Claim Number:']/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

> AND

```
//div[@id='claim-num-success']/b[text()='Status:']/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

But Selenium doesn't allow you to locate an element using text node in xpath. So you can use `JavascriptExecutor` to evaluate your xpath and locate the element using text node.

This is how you can full-fill your requirement :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Object claimNo= js.executeScript("var value = document.evaluate(\"//div[@id='claim-num-success']/b[text()='Claim Number:']/following-sibling::text()[1]\",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ); return value.stringValue;");
System.out.println("Claim Number : "+ claimNo.toString());

Object Status= js.executeScript("var value = document.evaluate(\"//div[@id='claim-num-success']/b[text()='Status:']/following-sibling::text()[1]\",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ); return value.stringValue;");
System.out.println("Status : "+ Status.toString());
```